# How to match 2 fields in Mongo collection with one of the field being inside an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection `Items` of objects say :

```
[{"Item" : "Apple",
  "Company" : "American Foods",
  "Items" : [{"name" : "Banana", "name" : "Orange", "name" : "Apple", "name" : "Avocado"}]},
 {"Item" : "Mango",
  "Company" : "American Foods",
  "Items" : [{"name" : "Banana", "name" : "Orange", "name" : "Apple", "name" : "Avocado"}]},
 {"Item" : "Banana",
  "Company" : "Indian Foods",
  "Items" : [{"name" : "Banana", "name" : "Orange", "name" : "Apple", "name" : "Avocado"}]}
]
```

I want to write a mongo aggregate query which takes an input to return all the documents which match any `Item = Items[i].name` AND `Company = input`.

Suppose If I search with `input = American Foods` then the query will return 1 document from the collection (as Mango is not present in Items and the company for Banana is Indian Foods):

```
{"Item" : "Apple",
  "Company" : "American Foods",
  "Items" : [{"name" : "Banana", "name" : "Orange", "name" : "Apple", "name" : "Avocado"}]}
```

Comment: You can look at [`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `$expr` operator:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $eq: [ "$Company", "American Foods"]
          },
          {
            $in: [ "$Item", "$Items.name" ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OAwv2mZhUOu)

**Note:** Your `Items` array has wrong JSON syntax, it should have separate items

Comment: Yeah sorry. I just realized. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nodejs + Mongoose

Can you try this way?

```
var input = "American Foods";
Items.find({},function(err, list_items){
    if(err){
        console.log("err: " + err);
    }else{
        if(list_items.length > 0){
            list_items.forEach(item_tmp => {
                Items.find( { Company : input,"Items": { name:  item_tmp.Item} }, function(err, data){
                    // doing something
                } )
            })
        }
    }
})
```